# Migration From Struts 2.3.37 to 2.5.33

Tags: struts2, struts, struts2-jquery-plugin

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration
I have followed the above page to migrate from struts 2.3 to strut 2.5. I have

1. changed.package name related to struts mentioned in the above link
2. updated all struts dependencies to 2.5.33
3. updated spring dependencies to 4(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+2.5)
4. Updated DTD for both struts.xml and tiles.xml
5. Added Struts Tiles listener in web.xml

I getting the following error when running on Tomcat .Can anyone suggest what to do to solve this?

```
16:33:07.435 [main] ERROR o.a.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Dispatcher initialization failed
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load configuration.
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:970)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Feb 12, 2024 4:33:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [StrutsPrepareAndExecute]
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/anweshan.s/Documents/31.1.2024/apache-tomcat-9.0.45/wtpwebapps/CoreWebapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:509)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/anweshan.s/Documents/31.1.2024/apache-tomcat-9.0.45/wtpwebapps/CoreWebapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [struts-prepare]
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/anweshan.s/Documents/31.1.2024/apache-tomcat-9.0.45/wtpwebapps/CoreWebapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:509)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.init(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/anweshan.s/Documents/31.1.2024/apache-tomcat-9.0.45/wtpwebapps/CoreWebapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
```

Answer (score 0):

In each struts2 plugin there's a `struts-plugin.xml` and even it's  related to your question I will suggest you to remove it from classpath configuration and deployment artifacts. Because you are probably not use struts2-jquery in your project, and that plugin is useless, and that's it prevents you from bootstrap your application causing an error, and it requires additional references on the classpath related to struts2-jquery that are absent or you don't use them.

If you use third party plugins with your project then you should contact the plugin project web site if you need a support because this plugin is not supported by the Apache Struts and might be deprecated as far as you might use an outdated version of the struts2-jquery-plugin.

Please use latest version of Struts2 jQuery Plugin. The version you have is 3.3.0 which is not compatible to Struts 2.5.x.

See [Struts2 jQuery Plugin Changelog](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/Changelog) for more details.